# The real URI of a PHP file?

Tags: php, uri

Is there anyway to get the current URI of a file in PHP, regardless of which file it is being included?

for example:

`a.php` is included in `b.php`

But I want to get the URI of the directory in which `a.php` is located in.

Comment: You can use dirname(__ FILE __); to get the server path of a.php, you will need to match that to the document_root and add the $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] to get the actual URI. I would type you a complete answer but im on an iphone ;) couldnt resist answering though!

Comment: Thank you Johan! I wish I could mark this as the correct answer haha :)

Comment: what URI you're talking about? filesystem path you mean? What for you need it?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, no I meant this `http://example.com/a.php_directory/`

Comment: @Mohammad that's nonsense then. included file directory won't help you even a bit. What for you need this a.php_directory?

Comment: I was just trying to automate a WordPress config file across more than one domain, however it needs the absolute path and uri of its own location hard coded in itself.

Comment: i still see no point in this. filesystem path has almost nothing to do with URI, I can't see how it can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current URI can normally be composed from `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (except the hash identifier, `#foo`, which is not even sent to the server).

You can find further reference [here](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices) but it's normally easier to [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) the `$_SERVER` array.

**Clarification:** a file can have one URL, many or none at all. There isn't necessarily a 1 to 1 mapping between files and URLs.

---

If we have this file layout:

- `/home/foo/htdocs/foo.php`

  ```
    <?php
    include('./lib/utils.php');
    blah();
  ```
- `/home/foo/htdocs/lib/utils.php`

  ```
    <?php
    function blah(){
    }
  ```

... where `/home/foo/htdocs` is the document root, the way to to obtain the URL of the directory where `utils.php` lies is to read `__FILE__` from within `utils.php` and replace leading `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with the site's protocol and path. E.g.:

```
<?php

if( isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ){
    $directory = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    $document_root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    $base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' .
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    if( strpos($directory, $document_root)===0 ){
        echo $base_url . str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', substr($directory, strlen($document_root)));
    }
}
```

This code may need some tweaking (not all web servers create the same variables) and of course there's no guarantee that the directory's URL will be reachable or useful.

Nota: an earlier version of this answer mentioned `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. While it's fine most of the time, it won't include the port number when a non-default port is being used. `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` does.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - That isn't what I infer from the question. I suggest you provide your own answer.

Comment: `a.php is included in b.php. I want to get the URI of the directory in which a.php is located in.` says it pretty straightforward. isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "real" URL for a file, as that would imply a 1:1 mapping between URLs and files. Virtual Directories allow for a file to have many different names.

However, if you just want the file system path of `a.php`, then try `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `realpath(__FILE__)` to get the directory in the filesystem. You should be able to translate that to the URI.

[realpath()](https://www.php.net/realpath)

Comment: you mixed up realpath with dirname. `__FILE__` already contains real path

Answer (score 0):

Using Johan's answer in the comment section, we have:
This answer is highly dependent on your directory structure, make sure you explode by the last folder that leads to your www root! This could be either 'htdocs' or 'public_html' depending on your host.

```
$my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$this_uri_dir = explode('public_html', dirname(__FILE__)); //this assumes you don't have multiple folders named 'public_html'
echo 'http://'.$my_domain.$this_uri_dir[1].'/';
```